# unknown class long for a method with long type arguement

Tags: android, react-native

I have this number in my javascript: 1620248807120. I want to pass this to a method but java complains integer number too large when I do:

```
 @ReactMethod
 funName(int v)
```

It compiles but the value is somehow different than the one provided (I guess it was cast as an int?).

When I do

```
 @ReactMethod
 funName(long v)
```

it crashes with error message after I start the application:

```
        Got unknown argument class: long
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the React Native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android#argument-types), JavaScript `number` types are converted to a `double` in Java when passed across the native bridge. As far as I can tell [from the Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3), the largest whole (non-fractional) number a `Double` can store in Java is 2^53 - 1, or 9,007,199,254,740,991. So if you set your parameter data type in your `@ReactMethod` to `double`, you should be able to pass `1620248807120` to the method:

```java
@ReactMethod
funName(double v)
```

Or you could convert your number to a `string` in JavaScript and accept a `string` in your `@ReactMethod`, then convert the `string` to a `long` (if you are only expecting whole numbers), or a `double` if you are expecting fractional numbers:

```java
@ReactMethod
funName(string v) {
  long vLong = Long.parseLong(v);
}
```

or

```java
@ReactMethod
funName(string v) {
  double vDouble = Double.parseDouble(v);
}
```